# Where to ask questions about web CMSs?

Tags: support, scope

Where would I ask a question about a web-based content management system (e.g. WordPress)?

Answer (score 4):

Depends:

- Development (i.e. writing code): [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
- General website administration: [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)
- Wordpress-specific: [Wordpress.SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)
- Subjective, development-related comparisons (e.g. "What's your favorite CMS to develop in?"): [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Also in the proposal stage:

- Drupal-specific: [Drupal Answers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2978/drupal-answers)
- Joomla-specific: [Joomla Answers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/9494/joomla-answers)
- CMS development: [CMS Development](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2608/cms-development)

At some point, in the distant future, I'm sure the overlap between all of these sites will get worked out. *Maybe.*

Comment: You should really mention the [Wordpress Support Forum](http://wordpress.org/support/). There is a lot of info there, some of the WP developers hang out there (and on the mailing lists you can sign up for if you go there), and it's been around a while.

Comment: The assumption is that, by virtue of asking on Meta.StackExchange, the asker wants to know in the context of the Stack Exchange ecosystem. There are literally dozens of sites that could be added to the list if it's opened up to the entire internet.

Comment: Only one of those dozens is the source.

Comment: The question is for web-based content management systems (in general, and only for *example*, WordPress): there's a canonical support forum for every CMS out there. And as I alluded to, the Stack Exchange ecosystem is set apart from the rest of the internet. If it wasn't, Wordpress/Joomla/Drupal Answers would have never gotten off the ground.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the **[Beta Wordpress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)** after exploring the native **[Wordpress Support Forum](http://wordpress.org/support/)** (the Wordpress site has several searchable mailing lists, and you can ask questions / participate in the lists too).

For general CMS stuff, maybe the **[Beta Webmasters Stackexchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)**.

*Additionally Stack Overflow does have a **[wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress)** tag and several other Wordpress related tags.*

Comment: Thanks. I was just using WordPress as an example. I think I actually want to ask for a CMS recommendation for a project.